# What's the equivalent of GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream::factory in Guzzle 6?

Tags: php-7, guzzle6, guzzle

I've the following code which needs to be migrated into Guzzle 6:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream;
use Drupal\Testing\PHPUnit\DrupalTestCase;
class OpsAbstractTest extends DrupalTestCase {

  public function responseMock($value, $code = 200) {
    $body = Stream::factory(json_encode($value));
    return new Response($code, ['Content-type' => 'application/json'], $body);
  }

}
```

The code fails after upgrading to Guzzle 6 with:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream' not found

The code is using the [static factory method](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/streams.html?highlight=GuzzleHttp%5CStream%5CStream#creating-streams) which seems to be [non-existing](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/search.html?q=stream%20factory) in Guzzle 6.

What would be the equivalent static factory method to use in Guzzle 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use the static factory method anymore. The encoded JSON code can be passed directly into parameter. Check the examples below.

#### Guzzle 5

```
$response = new \GuzzleHttp\Message\Response(
    b200,
    ['Content-Type' = 'application/json'],
    \GuzzleHttp\Streams\Stream::factory(json_encode(['foo' => 'bar' ])
);
```

<sup>Source: [`aerisweather/GuzzleHttpMock`](https://github.com/aerisweather/GuzzleHttpMock) (`README.md`).</sup>

#### Guzzle 6

```
$response = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response(
    200,
    ['Content-Type' = 'application/json'],
    json_encode(['foo' => 'bar' ]
);
```

<sup>Source: [`systemhaus/GuzzleHttpMock`](https://github.com/systemhaus/GuzzleHttpMock) (`README.md`)</sup>

---

Check also [this commit (`36a7ef`)](https://github.com/systemhaus/GuzzleHttpMock/commit/36a7eff0ef54b4931f9ca319edf4921c85f2023d) for more detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for()` function.

Comment: Under v7, you want to use `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::streamFor()`